# Python. Вывод числительных

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for number in numbers:
    if number == 1:
        print ('1st')
    elif number == 2:
        print ('2nd')
    elif number == 3:
        print ('3rd')
    else:
        print (number,'th')
```

Используйте цепочку if-elif-else в цикле для вывода правильного окончания числительного для каждого числа. Программа должна выводить числительные «1st 2nd 3rd
4th 5th 6th 7th 8th 9th»

Comment: И в чем вопрос?

Comment: Выводится вот это:                                                                                                                             1st
2nd 
3rd
4 th
5 th
6 th
7 th
8 th
9 th

Comment: Ну и? Все правильно

Comment: `print (number,'th')` исправить на `print (f'{number}th')` чтобы лишнего пробела не было и все

Comment: @Zhihar эх, а ведь можно было еще десяток елифов предложить... Для науки.

Comment: Код можно сократить? Не подскажите?

Answer (score 1):

Лишний пробел можно убрать так:

```
print(f"{number}th")
```

либо так:

```
print(number, "th", sep = "")
```

либо так:

```
print(str(number) + "th")
```

но самый правильный вариант это первый

С помощью словаря можно обойтись без `if`

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
dict_ = {1: "st", 2: "nd", 3: "rd"}

for number in numbers:
    print(str(number) + dict_.get(number, "th"))
```